# Split date value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a $scope object that has a date property. I am trying to split that date into dd, mm and yyyy so i can perform calculations based on the values.

JS:

```
$scope.expenses = [
    {
      amount: 100,
      SpentOn: '19/04/2014'
    },
    {
      amount: 350,
      SpentOn: '01/09/2013'
    }
  ];

$scope.MySplitDateFunction = function () {

    var data = [];
    var data = $scope.expenses.SpentOn.split('/');
    data.day = SpentOn[0];
    data.month = SpentOn[1];
    data.year = SpentOn[2];
    return data;

};
```

I am getting the following error: $scope.expenses.SpentOn is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since in your program $scope.expenses has two objects and you have not specifies which is that

Try this out

```
$scope.MySplitDateFunction = function () {

    var data = [];
    var data = $scope.expenses[0].SpentOn.split('/');
    return data;
};
```

Comment: thanks, in my example i have only provided 2 objects for example purposes.. The data will come from a JSON file with 50+ objects.

Comment: here you can add any one of objects and try

Comment: thanks that make sense, but once ive returned data, how can i access the mm or yyyy values directly to perform a calculation on.

Comment: you have the mm yyyy values in the `data` array itself right

Comment: Yup, can work with console.log(data[0]);
          console.log(data[1]);
          console.log(data[2]);

Comment: Im trying to split this question up into smaller components: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23780795/angularjs-ordering-and-parsing-data-in-a-ng-repeat-based-on-a-parent-ng-repea

Comment: thanks, that second fiddle makes a lot of sense. Are you able to help with that question in the comment above?

Answer (score 1):

`$scope.expenses` returns an array with 2 objects in it so you'll have to do something like

```
$scope.expenses[0].SpentOn // returns 19/04/2014
```

Or you can remove the `[]` to make it an object and not an array of objects

Comment: thanks, in my example i have only provided 2 objects for example purposes.. The data will come from a JSON file with 50+ objects.

Comment: @OamPsy it still remains an array so you'll have to loop thru all of the objects

Comment: thanks, i am still seeing Error: SpentOn is not defined

Answer (score 1):

`$scope.expenses` seems to be an array with objects, you have to try

```
$scope.expenses[0].SpentOn
```

Comment: @DavalMarthak - thanks, i am still seeing Error: SpentOn is not defined